# Office (Excel) Web Add-in not running (localhost)

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, officedev

Currently we have more and more problems with the development of Office Web Add-ins.

<s>Months ago we started not being able to launch web add-ins from Visual Studio with the debugger. The error message in the output window was "The program 'excel.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).". In the EventLog of Windows we could not find any logs for this at all. Unfortunately this problem still exists and there is still no solution.</s>

Since the add-ins could still be started with visual studio without the debugger attached, we used the [Microsoft Edge DevTools Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/p/microsoft-edge-devtools-preview/9mzbfrmz0mnj?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) to debug the code.

However, we currently have the problem that the add-ins no longer start in any Office application. First, the error "We can't open this add-in from localhost" occured. So we proceeded according to the following [microsoft documentation (loopback exemption)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/cannot-open-add-in-from-localhost) to fix this. Unfortunately without success. [Option 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/cannot-open-add-in-from-localhost#option-1-use-command-to-add-a-local-loopback-exemption) had no effect at all and with [Option 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/cannot-open-add-in-from-localhost#option-2use-fiddler-to-add-a-local-loopback-exemption) the localhost error message was no longer displayed, but `This add-in could not be started. Close this dialog to ignore the problem or click "Restart" to try again.`

The Fiddler response contains the following message "[Fiddler] The connection to 'localhost' failed. 
Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d). 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException A connection could not be established because the target computer refused to connect 127.0.0.1:44332"

Unfortunately, we have not found a solution yet, but perhaps there is already one?

EDIT: Solved the `The program 'excel.exe' has exited with code -1` by performing the online repair of the "Microsoft 365" App once again. But the other problem still remains.

Answer (score -1):

One cause of this error is that the Microsoft Edge Web Viewer does not
have a loopback exemption. To resolve this issue, use either of these
options to add a local loopback exemption to Desktop App Web Viewer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/cannot-open-add-in-from-localhost

Comment: I have already tried the loopback exemption, unfortunately without much success. (See the description of the problem)

Comment: did you try Web Viewer add-ins and see if the add-ins can display it properly, This will rule out whether it is an excel problem or a plug-in problem

Comment: We can install Office Add-ins from store and we can sideload Add-ins from our own server (or from local IIS) without problems. Only if we start any Add-in (no matter which) with Visual Studio, we have the described problems. This makes it difficult to customize and make changes for the add-in.